# Python : Getting YouTube Analytics Data (from API) Into a DataFrame

Tags: python, statistics, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Dear developer friends,

I hope you are well,

I begin with Python Language (I follow some courses) and I have decided to improve my skills to try to analyse a Youtube Channel (Amixem, a fench youtuber).

So, I try to followed [this tutorial](https://addendanalytics.com/getting-youtube-analytics-data-into-power-bi-using-python-script/) to get YouTube Data (from API) Into a DataFrame (to make some statistics in a second time).

I don't uderstand which variable is expected line 35 (code available below) instead of this variable video_ids:

```
for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 40):
```

I have :

```
NameError: name 'video_ids' is not defined
```

I replace "video_ids" by "videos" (the total videos of Amixem - 580 videos - to stop the count) :

```
for i in range(0, len(videos), 40):
```

I have :

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found
```

So I try to fix this problem with :

```
for i in range(0, len(videos), 40):
    res = (youtube).videos().list(id=",".join(str(v) for v in videos),part="statistics").execute()
```

So I have :

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos returned "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter."
```

I'm a little bit disappointed.
Could you help me ?

My code below :

```
#Importing required packages
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd

#Creating Objects
youTubeApiKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
youtube= build("youtube","v3",developerKey=youTubeApiKey)
channelId = "UCgvqvBoSHB1ctlyyhoHrGwQ"

#Calling Data from API
statchanneldata=youtube.channels().list(part="statistics",id=channelId).execute()
statchannel=statchanneldata["items"][0]["statistics"]

#Getting Snippet Data
snippetdata=youtube.channels().list(part="snippet",id=channelId).execute()

#Getting Details of all videos
contentdata=youtube.channels().list(id=channelId,part="contentDetails").execute()
playlist_id = contentdata["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]
videos = [ ]
next_page_token = None
while 1:
    res = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=playlist_id,
                                   part="snippet",
                                   maxResults=10,
                                   pageToken=next_page_token).execute()

    videos += res["items"]
    next_page_token = res.get("nextPageToken")
    if next_page_token is None:
        break

#Getting the statistics of each video
stats = []
for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 40):
    res = (youtube).videos().list(id=",".join(video_ids[i:i+40]),part="statistics").execute()
    stats += res["items"]

#Collecting All Information in a List & creating a dataframe
title=[ ]
liked=[ ]
disliked=[ ]
views=[ ]
url=[ ]
comment=[ ]

for i in range(len(videos)):
    title.append((videos[i])["snippet"]["title"])
    url.append("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+(videos[i])["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"])
    liked.append(int((stats[i])["statistics"]["likeCount"]))
    disliked.append(int((stats[i])["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]))
    views.append(int((stats[i])["statistics"]["viewCount"]))
    comment.append(int((stats[i])["statistics"]["commentCount"]))
    data={"title":title,"url":url,"liked":liked,"disliked":disliked,"views":views,"comment":comment}
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Thanks,
Aurélien.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code:

```
for i in range(0, len(videos), 40):
    res = (youtube).videos().list(id=",".join(str(v) for v in videos),part="statistics").execute()
```

With:

```
for i in range(0, len(videos)):
    res = (youtube).videos().list(id=videos[i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']),part="statistics").execute()
```

Comment: Hello baba dook. Thanks to help me. I try it but i have :
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. 
I try ti fix it, but without success.

Comment: Try the edited answer, if it works upvote and mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the solution :

You just need to define video_ids :

> video_ids = list(map(lambda x:x['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'],
> videos))

So, we are :

> #Getting the statistics of each video stats = [] video_ids = list(map(lambda x:x['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], videos)) for
> i in range(0, len(video_ids), 40):
> res = (youtube).videos().list(id=",".join(video_ids[i:i+40]),part="statistics").execute()
> stats += res["items"]